# bash while statement

Tags: bash, while-loop, pipe

I have 2 different scripts doing basically the same: counting the subdirectories in the current directory:

```
c=0

ls -l | grep "^d" | while read zeile
do
    c=`expr $c + 1`
    echo $c
done

echo "Subdirs: $c"
```

and

```
c=0

while read zeile
do
    c=`expr $c + 1`
    echo $c
done < <(ls -l | grep "^d")

echo "Subdirs: $c"
```

My Problem is, that in the first version, "c" seems to lose it's value after the while-loop has finished.

The outputs

1)

```
1
2
3
Subdirs: 0
```

2)

```
1
2
3
Subdirs: 3
```

Can anyone of you explain to me, why this is happening?

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l` to get your count (although it'll also count the current directory). Omit the `-maxdepth 1` option to count subdirectories as well.

Comment: @choroba has the right answer, but in general to count files I'd recommend `count=$(find . -printf x | wc -c)` - Works with *any* file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, the assignment to c happens after the `|`, i.e. in a subshell. You cannot change a variable in a parent shell from a subshell.
BTW, why do not you use `let c++` instead of backquotes and expr?

Comment: Thanks - does that mean, everything after the | happens in a subshell, or only in this case?
I didn't know abotu let c++ - I'm a beginner in bash scripting

Comment: No thats the general behaviour. In your second command you didn't create a new sub-shell. You used process substitution so the variable retained it's value.

Comment: In bash, any shell commands anywhere in a pipeline (i.e. before *or* after `|`) will execute in a subshell.  Some other shells are a bit different, see [BashFAQ #024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If I have to count sub directories then I would use either of these 2 commands:

```
find . -regex ".\{2,\}" -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l
ls -l | grep "^d" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

You [should not use `ls` in that way](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

You should use a for loop and a glob to iterate over files or directories.

```
for f in *
do
    if [[ -d $f ]]
    then
        (( c++ ))
    fi
done
echo "Subdirs: $c"
```

or

```
for f in */
do
    (( c++ ))
done
echo "Subdirs: $c"
```

Here's a hackish way:

```
arr=(*/); echo "Subdirs: ${#arr[@]}"
```

You will probably want to use `nullglob` and `dotglob` with any of the above. See [BashFAQ/004](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) for more information.

Choroba is correct regarding the subshell issue.